# txt file suddenly shows strange characters

Tags: windows-8, notepad, characters

I have a Notepad file (.txt) in which I have latin characters written. this file is in my dropbox folder. It contained something like: "P@SSW0rd". I tried to open that file today and it shows me some strange characters like: ]“NŽYƒ

I sent it to a friend and he also can't see the latin characters, he sees the strange ones.

I also tried to open it via dropbox on web, and Chrome also shows the same strange characters.

This happens with a lot of files (not all). How can I fix this? Because these files are really important to me :( I have windows 8 OS. I formatted my pc a couple of days ago but I don't think that that is related to the issue.

Comment: can you post real strange characters? did you tryed to convert to/from UTF8 (using notepad++ for exmaple)?

Comment: @befzz Here's how another file with the same problem looks like: http://prntscr.com/8w755a

Comment: @befzz And yes I tried and it still doesnt show the correct characters,

Comment: can you share/post a part of file(from beginning). i will try to encode/decode it too. dont want to giveup!

Comment: @befzz Here it is: http://www.filedropper.com/fiddler
Thanks a lot!

Comment: meh... maximum: `M+ICE.+BFU-wB:+IKwEVA,+BJAEEiAeB` .. ohh.. i think its encrypted somehow :D. And it dont looks like compression. Check for malware/virus...;(